# How to test for default values in Golang when yaml has already initialized the value?

Tags: go

I'm writing a daemon's configuration handler and utilizing the `yaml` package to do so.  Importing my file works like this:

```
package daemon

import (
    "ioutil"
    "log"

    "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
)

type daemonConfig struct {
    BindAddress string `yaml:"bind_address"`
    BindPort    int    `yaml:"bind_port"`
    VerifySSL   bool   `yaml:"verify_ssl"`
}
```

I easily unmarshall data from my YAML files like so:

```
func (config *daemonConfig) getConf() *daemonConfig {
    yamlFile, err := ioutil.ReadFile("config.yaml")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Unable to open config.yaml:", err)
    }
    err = yaml.Unmarshal(yamlFile, config)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Failed to unmarshall config.yaml:", err)
    }
    config, err = setDefaults(config)

    return config
}
```

My question is regarding my custom setDefaults function.  If a field isn't provided, like `bind_port` or `bind_address`, I'd like to just set them to defaults:

```
func setDefaults(config *daemonConfig) (*daemonConfig, error) {
    if len(config.BindAddress) <= 0 {
        config.BindAddress = "0.0.0.0"
    }
    if config.BindPort == 0 {
        config.BindPort = 9999
    }

    return config, nil
}
```

You'll note I'm not setting a default to `verify_ssl`; when `yaml` unmarshalls this and fails to find the field, it initializes the `bool` as `false`, which is precisely the opposite of what I want the default behavior to be.  I'd prefer the user to explicitly set verification of SSL to be off, instead of having it off by default if not specified.  If I have a totally empty `config.yaml`, and expect the default values to be set, it will always put `verify_ssl` as false (this log is from elsewhere in the application):

```
2019/02/19 03:56:08 Currently loaded config: {0.0.0.0 9999 false}
```

How would I go about, if this field is not present in the YAML fields that are being unmarshalled, to checking if the line exists?  I could just read the file manually and check for that parameter first, but I was wondering if there's a more elegant way with what I have; otherwise, I'll just use `ioutil` and string checking to do it.  Thanks!

Comment: have you tried to use a pointer ?

Comment: Not sure I follow, sorry; how would a pointer to the field in the struct that is unmarshalled help, if it still points to a `false` value by default?  I don't know whether the user explicitly set `false` or if it's actually an empty field, and I don't want to accidentally overwrite their settings.  Sorry if I'm being dense.

Comment: If `yaml` works like the `json` package, then you can have a `VerifySSL *bool` field, and it will default to `nil` rather than (a pointer to) `false`. Might need the `omitempty` flag as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to [Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14637/thomas) and [mh-cbon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4466350/mh-cbon) I found out I can just use a pointer for this.  If I change my `VerifySSL` field to utilize a pointer and add `omitempty`:

```
type daemonConfig struct {
    BindAddress string `yaml:"bind_address"`
    BindPort    int    `yaml:"bind_port"`
    VerifySSL   *bool  `yaml:"verify_ssl",omitempty`
}
```

I can simply dereference the field in the struct to get the true value of what `yaml` unmarshalled.  Setting defaults is as easy as:

```
func setDefaults(config *daemonConfig) (*daemonConfig, error) {
    if len(config.BindAddress) <= 0 {
        config.BindAddress = "0.0.0.0"
    }
    if config.BindPort == 0 {
        config.BindPort = 9999
    }
    if config.VerifySSL == nil {
        ssl := true
        config.VerifySSL = &ssl
    }

    return config, nil
}
```

If it's loaded in the file, `config.VerifySSL` will contain the address of the `bool`, so it won't be `nil`, and if it's truly not in the file at all then the field is simply `nil` and I can set it or get it via a pointer.

EDIT:
Just a note, if your `VerifySSL` pointer is nil, you can't assign it like this:

```
*config.VerifySSL = true
```

That's dereferencing a `nil` pointer.  I've updated the solution to include something more manageable.